# Writing to a text file and reading it into a table is giving weird results (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to use a text file as a temporary database. Problem is that when I write it to the text file it writes out of order. It then displays it in the table that way. Can anyone see why this is happening?

[image]

Here is my method for writing to the file.

```
public void writeDtLogsCsv() throws IOException {
    Writer writer = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\savedLogs.txt");
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        for (AddLogs log : logView) {

            String text = log.getDate() + ";" + log.getName() + ";" + log.getDowntime() + ";" + 
                          log.getEquipment() + ";" + log.getProblem() + ";" + log.getFix() + "\r\n";

            writer.write(text);


        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

Here is my method to read from the file.

```
public void readCSV() {

    String CsvFile = "C:\\savedLogs.txt";
    String FieldDelimiter = ",";

    BufferedReader br;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CsvFile));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] fields = line.split(FieldDelimiter, -1);

            AddLogs record = new AddLogs();       
            logView.add(record);

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddLogs.class.getName())
                .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddLogs.class.getName())
                .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: We don't know what's performing the ordering and how, or where you've got the logs from. You should a) review what's providing you the data in `logView`; b) check the contents of the file directly in a text editor.

Comment: What is the **expected** order of the list? Is the example picture the current result or the **expected**? Also what Operating System are you developing on..?

Comment: You should never start variables with lowercase (except `static final` ones). And **never** swallow exceptions.

Comment: The image of the table is current result. Mike M. should always be in the Name column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I noticed after looking at `writeDtLogsCsv()` again.

1. You aren't writing out `,` into the file as your separator. Instead, you are writing `;`.
2. Your newline character is different per operating system. `\r\n` is the standard for Windows, while `\n` is the standard for MacOS and Linux

I would change the following:

```
for (AddLogs log : logView) {

    String text = log.getDate() + "," + log.getName() + "," + log.getDowntime() + "," + 
                  log.getEquipment() + "," + log.getProblem() + "," + log.getFix();

    writer.write(text);
    writer.newLine(); // Insert a new line character
}
```

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--) of `writer.newLine();`

> Writes a line separator. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline ('\n') character.

Comment: I changed the semicolons to commas and added writer.newLine();. IDE says cant find symbol newLine().

Comment: @ShannonBoileau Try changing `Writer writer = null;` to `BufferedWriter writer = null;`. Or you can try `writer.write(System.lineSeparator())` if you have Java 7+